# HTML5 Validation vs PHP Validation

Tags: php, html, validation

When is comes to form validation, which is the best method to proceed with? With HTML5, you can validate the e-mail address and telephone number but usually I would do this with PHP, so which method is better? Or should I validate the input in HTML5 and PHP?

Comment: You should always validate server side, the rest is mainly for usability (you can never rely on client side validation)

Comment: Validate with markup language?

Comment: @webarto: "_Validate with markup language?_": Yes, it is possible and it is the "future". See [this article](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/) for details and examples.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both.

**Rule of thumb:** 
Validate client-side to provide users with a better experience. 
Validate server-side to ensure 100% the data you receive is what you expect.

Answer (score 3):

Always validate with a server side programming language, additionally you could use a client side validation. The reason for this is that everything can be modified client side and thus bypass any client side validation. It's not even hard and there are a lot of tools available for people to modify the html and/or Javascript to submit whatever they want.

The golden rule is, never trust the user. Expect the worst and prepare for that. You **can** and **should** use tools such as firebug or other web developer tools to try things out.

Answer (score 1):

You should do both. HTML5 and/or JavaScript validation on the client-side to save the user a page load, and PHP validation because you can never, ever fully trust the client-side.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer both. It is nice when filling out a form to be notified if something doesn't match. However you can't rely on JS validation as it is easily bypassed so server side is required.

Answer (score 0):

The answer both is correct. Not a preference (as some have stated) but a requirement. All HTML (including HTML5) can be edited directly on your page via the browser. Just like using Firebug to edit this page's title, you can edit the HTML input validators and if they don't have server-side validation, it will accept anything you put in there. Handling validation with HTML5 only is like inviting hackers to corrupt all of your db tables. Do you want that?

I found this last comment on this stupid guy's site as a clear example: http://demosthenes.info/blog/462/Goodbye-JQuery-Validation-HTML5-Form-Errors-With-CSS3

Answer (score 0):

Most of the professional programmers have the approach of validating input fields with server side scripting language. Server side form validation using PHP is better than HTML5 and client side form validations in a number of ways:

1. HTML5 contains few attributes which automatically validates input fields for example:email,telephone,etc. These attribtues are limited. whereas in real world, there are many forms which have some fields which cant be directly validated through HTML5.
2. If you are thinking about clients side valdiation using javscript as the second option then keep in mind that javascript can be turned off in browser. so it will ultimately affect the user experience.so its better to valdiate your forms through server side scripting lanugae like PHP.
3. You should adopt the above approach for websites containing sensitive data. but